# Drupal 7 Conditional Fields Module: Displaying fields based on user permissions

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I'm fairly new to working with Drupal 7, and am currently working on my first "larger" project. Right now, we're using the Conditional Fields module to handle lots of things for hiding/showing fields based on other field options within the form. However, is it possible to hide/show fields based on a current user's permissions (e.g. admin being the only person who should see a specific field)?

I'm aware that this (I think) is possible using the `form_alter()` hooks, but was more curious if this was possible through the Conditional Fields Module?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly program your own module and implement [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to acomplish this task. However, [Field Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module provides what you need:

> The Field Permissions module allows site administrators to set field-level permissions to edit, view and create fields on any entity.